Word with \texttt{} is exceeding right margin -- how to force it to the next line? (*not* break it)
I have this line in my book:
La forma más fácil de compilar Cython es utilizando un archivo de \textit{setup}, veamos el \texttt{particulas-5-setup.py}:

My problem is that the filename at the end of the sentence is exceeding the width marging:

First, let's take this out of the question: I do NOT want for that file name to be split and part of it go to the next line. It's a file name, splitting would make it too confusing.
What I do want is for latex to just put the whole word (particulas-5-setup.py) in the next line.
Is there a way to achieve that?
Thank you!!

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Are you sure that readers will be confused if there's a line break inside particulas-5-setup.py? Surely they must understand that it's just a filename. (If they don't, you have some major comprehension issues to take care of...) I'd consider loading the xurl package and changing \texttt{particulas-5-setup.py} to \path{particulas-5-setup.py}.

\sloppypar possibly? but I would rewrite the sentence rather than use that.

@cfr It is \begin{sloppypar}…\end{sloppypar} not \sloppypar. Otherwise the \sloppy of \sloppypar would be valid forever (resp. until the end of the current group, which can be till the end of the document).

@cabohah thanks.

I can think of two solutions.

Employ a macro called, say, \filenameA that encases the \texttt directive in an \mbox directive. This also requires suppressing full paragraph indentation (via a \raggedright directive). This approach guarantees that no filename will be broken across lines; however, the suppression of full justification may not be acceptable to you. For sure, though, I wouldn't employ \begin{sloppypar} (and, later, \end{sloppypar}) to "restore" full justification for the paragraph in question. (Thanks to @cabobah for a related comment.)

Go against your proclaimed stricture against prohibiting line breaks in file names and employ the \path macro of the url package, which allows line breaks at arbitrary positions. Your concern that line breaks in file names would confuse readers could be mitigated effectively by giving the argument of \filenameB a unique color ("Indigo" in the example below). Speaking for myself (who else?!), I'd say that the odds that this method will confuse your readers should be negligible. :-)



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % predefine 'Indigo'

% Method A: Employ \mbox macro, require use of  '\raggedright'
\newcommand\filenameA[1]{\mbox{\ttfamily #1}}

% Method B: Employ '\path' macro of 'xurl' package
\usepackage{xurl} % for '\path' macro
\newcommand\filenameB[1]{\textcolor{Indigo}{\path{#1}}}

\begin{document}

% Application of method A
\begingroup
\raggedright % suppress full justfication
\setlength\parindent{1.5em} % optional: restore paragraph indentation

La forma más fácil de compilar Cython es utilizando 
un archivo de \textit{setup}, veamos el 
\filenameA{particulas-5-setup.py}: 
\lipsum[1][1-5] % add five sentences of filler text

\endgroup

\bigskip

% Application of method B

La forma más fácil de compilar Cython es utilizando 
un archivo de \textit{setup}, veamos el 
\filenameB{particulas-5-setup.py}: 
\lipsum[1][1-5] % add five sentences of filler text

\end{document}


\endsloppypar is defined as \par and therefore does not revert the changes of \sloppypar, which is defined as \par\sloppy. The correct LaTeX syntax is therefore \begin{sloppypar}…\end{sloppypar}, but not \sloppypar …\endsloppypar. Unfortunately using \sloppypar (with or without \endsloppypar) is a quite often seen mistake.

@cabohah - Thanks for pointing out this issue. I'll update my answer accordingly.
